# dpkg "missing version" for libcgns2-dbg in /var/lib/dpkg/available — can't do update - how can I fix this?

Tags: 12.04, updates

```
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 839085 package 'libcgns2-dbg':
 missing description
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 839085 package 'libcgns2-dbg':
 missing version
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

This message I got after failure of installation of updates. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 839085 package 'libcgns2-dbg':
missing description
```

From the above error report, it was clearly shown that description for a specific package is missing in the file `/var/lib/dpkg/available`. So delete the current available file and move or copy the backup file to it's location.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's any merit in going back to an old `available` file. It's a very temporary file (unlike `status`) so we can just rebuild it:

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo apt-get update
```

If you're still getting issues after that, there's something wrong in your repositories. I can only find this in 12.04 and my 12.04 machines seem to be fine... That suggests you might have it coming in from another repository... Check and get back to us.